# C# Nwaves "DiscreteSignal1 + DiscreteSignal2" superimposing operation results a giant peak from 0 Hz up to 17k+ Hz in the middle

Tags: signal-processing, wav, superimpose

I have two signals (out of wav files), both are mono wav files of 37500 Hz sample rate.

File 1 is output.wav: [image: file 1 'output.wav']

File 2 is saved_mono.wav: [image: file 2 'saved_mono.wav']

I apply superimposing ("+") operation for the two Discrete signals:

```
    // shiftedSignal is output.wav
    // outSignal is saved_mono.wav
    
    //This is how I read it:
    WaveFile shiftedWav;
    using (var stream = new FileStream("output.wav", FileMode.Open))
    {
        shiftedWav = new WaveFile(stream);
    }
    DiscreteSignal shiftedSignal = shiftedWav[Channels.Left];

    DiscreteSignal mergedSignal = shiftedSignal + outSignal;

    waveFileOut = new WaveFile(mergedSignal);
    using (var stream = new FileStream("merged.wav", FileMode.Create))
    {
        waveFileOut.SaveTo(stream);
    }
```

As the result, I have merged.wav file and it has a giant peak in the middle:
[image: superimposing result - merged.wav file with a giant peak]

Both input wav files have the same sample rate of 37500 and the same bitrate of 600 kbps.

**Where did it come from and how do I fix it?**

Just to make sure, I tried to concatenate these signals:

```
DiscreteSignal mergedSignal = shiftedSignal.Concatenate(outSignal);
```

And it comes out OK:
[image: Concatenate operation]

Comment: I tried using ffmpeg for the same operation: "ffmpeg.exe" -i "output.wav" -i "saved_mono.wav" -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first,volume=2 wav_ffmpeg_merged.wav" Result is quite similar: https://imgur.com/a/buxwk2p

Comment: Temporary solution for now is to attenuate output.wav by 10dB. No more weird giant peaks. But I still wonder why it happens..